# Linear Regression training with a small dataset

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with a total of 58 samples. The dataset has two columns "measured_signals" and "people_in_area". Due to it, I am trying to train a Linear Regression model using python's Scikit-learn to predict from the measured_signals” the people in the area.

The steps I do are the followings:

1. I use “sklearn.cross_validate. train_test_split” with a
   random_state=1 to split the dataset in x_train, y_train, x_test and
   y_test (I assume that the split makes 75% of the data for train
   and the remaining 25% for testing as I do not specify it).
2. I train the model with x_train and y_train
3. I use the x_test and y_test to obtain the R2_score of the model

This gives me a R2_score of 0.68.

However, if I change the order in which the data was before the Step 1, and then I repeat everything again, I get a R2_score of -0.05.

I see logically that as the data is in different order, using the same random state will give me different x_train, y_train, x_test and y_test values and due to it, I will be training the model with different data and obtaining different R2_scores.

However, does this mean that I should order the data somehow to properly train my model?

Comment: The difference in $R^2$ is rather alarming.  What do you mean about "using the same random state"?  W hat did you mean by changing the order of the data before step 1?

Comment: I do not see changing the order of the data for training.  Maybe you should look at trying cross-validation.  How many parameters are you using in the linear regression model?

Comment: Why is the $R^2$ negative

Comment: @not_bonferroni  There is a lot of discussion on this site about poor models and how they can lead to estimates of $R^2$ less than 0 and even cases where $R^2$ is greater than 1. This surprised me because these are sample estimates that should fall into the interval [0,1].

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I think I can imagine that when you do something unusual like suppressing the intercept, but there was no indication that was happening here. In ordinary linear regression wouldn't $R^2$ outside of (0,1) require the residual sum of squares either being negative or greater than the total sum of squares?

Comment: Yes. If you are not familiar with the posts maybe a search on the site using -negative $R^2$ would help I haven't read them all.  This suggestion is for the OP as well.

Comment: The data proceeds from two different times and first I was intercalating the values of Time1 with those at Time2.  Later, I remade the algorithm that gathers the data and changed the order and now it first gathers all the data from Time1 and then all the data from Time 2. That is what I meant by “changing the order of the data”. An example of what I mean is:

X = [**125.33**, 20.90, **79.95**, 23.42, … ]

Y= [**106**, 35, **40**, 29, …]

After the change of order

X=[**125.33, 79.95, 98.71,** …, 20.90, 23.42, …] 

Y= [**106, 40, 66, 63,** …, 35, 29,  … ]

Comment: With “using the same random state” I mean that if before changing the order I was using a “random state = 1”, after the position change I am using “random state =1”. 

What do you mean with how many parameters I am using? Do you mean hyperparameters for the model's tunning?

Comment: On my second question I meant the number of parameters in the final regression model. You mention hyperparameters.  Are you using a Bayesian prior?

Comment: I am only using one parameter (feature?) which is "number_of_measured_signals". I dont know what you mean by a "Bayesian prior". What I am using is the LinearRegression() method from Scikit-learn for obtaining a Linear Regression model to train (I hope that this answers your question).